# design phone directory that gives you the number back from the pool

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures

I came across below interview question and I was able to come up with below solution:

> Design a Phone Directory which supports the following operations:
>
> get: Provide a number which is not assigned to anyone. check: Check if
>   a number is available or not. release: Recycle or release a number..
>
> Example: // Init a phone directory containing a total of 3 numbers: 0,
>   1, and 2.
>
> PhoneDirectory directory = new PhoneDirectory(3);
>
> // It can return any available phone number. Here we assume it returns
>   0.
>
> directory.get();
>
> // Assume it returns 1.
>
> directory.get();
>
> // The number 2 is available, so return true.
>
> directory.check(2);
>
> // It returns 2, the only number that is left.
>
> directory.get();
>
> // The number 2 is no longer available, so return false.
>
> directory.check(2);
>
> // Release number 2 back to the pool.
>
> directory.release(2);
>
> // Number 2 is available again, return true.
>
> directory.check(2);

Interviewer was asking about how scalable this solution is if we are talking about 10 digit real phone number and also initialization takes about o(n) time. Also if we are deleting very frequently then keeping every single unused number can be wasteful in terms of space. He mentioned what happens if it is being used in multithreaded situation as well.

Is there anything we can optimize here?

```
public class PhoneDirectory {
  private final Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();
  private final Queue<Integer> available = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  private final int max;

  public PhoneDirectory(int maxNumbers) {
    this.max = maxNumbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumbers; i++) {
      this.available.offer(i);
    }
  }

  public int get() {
    Integer ret = available.poll();
    if (ret == null) {
      return -1;
    }
    used.add(ret);
    return ret;
  }

  public boolean check(int number) {
    if (number >= max || number < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return !used.contains(number);
  }

  public void release(int number) {
    if (used.remove(number)) {
      available.offer(number);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's not used then it's available. Which means you don't really need a queue of available numbers. You just need a counter/pointer for the next available number. I would call out that phone numbers shouldn't really be treated as numbers either. You could also just randomly pick a number and see if it's already used and keep picking until you get one then you only need to synchronize the set on updates. The cool thing about Set.add() is that it returns true if you were successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your interviewer suggests, it's not really practical to store all the unused phone numbers. A good clarification question I would like to see from candidates is what is the frequency of `get()` and `release()` calls. For real-world usage, they likely happen at about the same frequency, so the following approach will work:

We can optimize your solution by observing that anything not available is used, so it's not really necessary to store both states. Therefore, let's just keep track of the unused ones.

```java
public class PhoneDirectory {
  private final Set<Integer> available = new HashSet<Integer>();

  public PhoneDirectory(int maxNumbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumbers; i++) {
      this.available.add(i);
    }
  }

  public int get() {
    if (available.isEmpty()) {
      return -1;
    }
    int result = available.iterator().next();
    available.remove(result);
    return result;
  }

  public boolean check(int number) {
    return available.contains(number);
  }

  public void release(int number) {
    available.add(number);
  }
}
```

This gives us an amortized `O(1)` operation for all the calls except construction. To deal with optimizing the constructor call, we can do what [Jason Armstrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619441/design-phone-directory-that-gives-you-the-number-back-from-the-pool#comment94100597_53619441) alluded to and observe that we can keep track of the largest number offered so far, which implies that anything above that is available for offering. Additionally, we can exhaust our sparse set of available entries first if they exist. That would look something like this

```java
public class PhoneDirectory {
  private final Set<Integer> available = new HashSet<Integer>();
  private final int maxNumbers;
  private int largestOffered;

  public PhoneDirectory(int maxNumbers) {
    this.maxNumbers = maxNumbers;
    this.largestOffered = 0;
  }

  public int get() {
    if (available.isEmpty()) {
      return largestOffered < maxNumbers ? (++largestOffered) : -1;
    }
    int result = available.iterator().next();
    available.remove(result);
    return result;
  }

  public boolean check(int number) {
    return available.contains(number) || number > largestOffered;
  }

  public void release(int number) {
    available.add(number);
  }
}
```

That gets rid of our `O(n)` constructor. Going back to the initial assumption on the frequency, the reason this works is because if `get()` and `release()` happen relatively unpredictably at equal frequencies, then the size of `available` will remain relatively stable. This keeps the data structure size overall pretty efficient.

If the calls do not happen at the same frequency, for example we anticipate that `release()` can release large blocks at a time, then this problem becomes a lot more complicated. I believe in general this problem reduces to bitmap operations, and doing that space-efficiently is essentially bit-level compression.

With regards to the followup questions that your interviewer asked, they probably expect some discussion of distributed hash tables. You could also optimize the `available.iterator().next()` then `available.remove()` call as that can be simplified with some access to the underlying datastructure.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. I was thinking this line `int result = available.iterator().next();` is O(n) complexity?

Comment: Yes that line is worst case O(n) but it can be optimized with interior access to the underlying data source, again relying on the frequency of the calls. If that's unconvincing then you can also use a tree set instead for O(log n) for all the functions.